# Imputing NaNs using pandas's fillna() changes the dtype from float to object

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, imputation

So I am imputing some of my columns for the missing values. The columns were in numerical dtypes (float and integer)
As soon as I impute the missing values using fillna() with mean etc, the column's dtype is changed from float to object.
I wanted it to remain float. And find it a little inefficient to redo all dtypes.
Kindly help me with this.

Here is an example.

```
ser_original = pd.Series([1.0, 2.0, np.nan, 4.0, 5.0], dtype=float)

ser_imputed = ser_original.fillna(np.mean)
print('After imputation, the dtype is {}'.format(ser_imputed.dtype))
```

> After imputation, the dtype is **dtype('O')**

Please note that this is just a sample example I created here. I am working with a large datasets and have planned to impute multiple columns with different imputations. So please suggest the solution that helps handling multiple columns at once.

P.S. I find deploying for loops to be a little naive. Do comment if I am incorrect here.

Comment: What happens if you try `np.nanmean`?

Comment: I can try using that. But can you suggest for median and mode as well?

And for the sake of my clarity, why does it happen? Why is it converting the dtype from float to Object after imputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using a function rather than values

```
ser_original = pd.Series([1.0, 2.0, np.nan, 4.0, 5.0], dtype=float)
ser_imputed = ser_original.fillna(np.mean)
print(ser_imputed)
0                                      1.0
1                                      2.0
2    <function mean at 0x000002BCA05020D0>
3                                      4.0
4                                      5.0
dtype: object
```

Use the mean instead and it works fine

```
ser_imputed = ser_original.fillna(ser_original.mean())
print(ser_imputed)
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
dtype: float64
print(ser_imputed.dtype)
# dtype('float64')
```

If you have a dataframe, you can fill in NaNs in it by using `fillna()` as

```
df.fillna(df.mean())
```

where each column’s NaN will be replaced by the mean of that column.